# Fetch data from cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase

I have use same activity(CatagoriesActivity) with different title(English,Mathematic,History , Geography etc) for different buttons(btn_eng,btn_math etc).and creat collection(name-subject) and documents(name-Eng,Math etc) in cloud firestore. Now I want to fetch different data from cloud firestore for different subject. How can do it?

Comment: You need to provide some code you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to these for detailed help [Link1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data)
[Link2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
and read their documentation as well. And here you will find some example code [Link3](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781788624718/1/ch01lvl1sec12/reading-and-writing-to-realtime-database)